# Custom UIViewController animations WITHOUT A UINAVIGATIONCONTROLLER

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiviewcontroller

I have a camera view controller. I want to push it. But I want it to fade in while I push it. How do I do this. I'm not using a UINavigationController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You "push" a view controller onto a navigation stack. But when you present a view controller without navigation controller, you name it "present" (not "push"). Means the term "pushing" a view controller is hardly connected to `UINavigationController`.

So you could just google for something like "UIViewController custom transition" or anything similar.

[I did great success following a this great article by Teehan+Lax](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/). Just read it, it should lead you the right way.

**EDIT** Okay. I gonna add some info to provide a better answer for you.

First of all, you'll create a new subclass of `NSObject` and conform to the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` protocol:

```
@interface JWTransitionAnimator <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>
+ (JWTransitionAnimator *)transitionAnimatorForPresentation;
+ (JWTransitionAnimator *)transitionAnimatorForDismissal;
@end
```

Then you let the magic happen in your implementation:

```
@interface JWTransitionAnimator ()
@property (atomic, assign, getter=isPresenting) BOOL presenting;
@end

@implementation JWTransitionAnimator
+ (JWTransitionAnimator *)transitionAnimatorForPresentation {
    JWTransitionAnimator *animator = [[self alloc] init];
    [animator setPresenting:YES];

    return animator;
}
+ (JWTransitionAnimator *)transitionAnimatorForDismissal {
    return [[self alloc] init];
}

// implement the protocol:
- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitioningContext {
    return 0.3;    // or any other duration.
}
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitioningContext {
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitioningContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext UITransitionContextToViewController];

    UIView *fromView = [fromViewController view];
    UIView *toView = [toViewController view];

    if ([self isPresenting]) {
        [fromView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

        [[transitionContext containerView] addSubview:fromView];
        [[transitionContext containerView] addSubview:toView];

        [toView setAlpha:0.0];
        [toView setTransform:CGAffineTransformScale([fromView transform], 0.3, 0.3)];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
            [fromView setTintAdjustmentMode:UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed];

            [toView setAlpha:1.0];
            [toView setTransform:CGAffineTransformScale([toView transform], 1.0, 1.0)];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [transitionContext completeTransition:finished];
        }];
    }
    else {
        // reverse your animation here (change "fromView" for "toView" and vice-versa)
    }
}
```

Your presenting viewController must conform to the `UIViewControllerTransitionDelegate` protocol. Implement it as follows:

```
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {
    return [JWTransitionAnimator transitionAnimatorForPresentation];
}
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed {
    return [JWTransitionAnimator transitionAnimatorForDismissal];
}
```

The you present the view controller like this:

```
- (IBAction)presentViewController:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *yourVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];    // however you create it
    [yourVC setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationStyleCustom];
    [yourVC setTransitionDelegate:self];

    [self presentViewController:yourVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```